# Gradle could not find method XYZ for arguments.

Tags: gradle

a bit new to Gradle and Groovy trying to use the following task: http://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/docs/groovydoc/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/tasks/image/DockerPushImage.html

as folows:

```
task pushImageDev(type: DockerPushImage) {
    imageName "xxxxxx:5000/${project.name}-${appEnviroment}:${version}"

    registryCredentials {
        email = 'none@your.business'
        url = 'xxxxxx:5000'
        username =  'xxxxxx'
        password =  'xxxxxx'
    }
}
```

But I keep getting...

```
Could not find method registryCredentials() for arguments [build_21ymvy7kfomjn3daqwpuika10$_run_closure8$_closure18@dd69c19] on task ':pushImageDev' of type com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerPushImage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only use `registryCredentials` method within the `docker` task configuration, and not in a custom task, like

```
docker {
    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://gcr.io'
        username = '_json_key'
        password = file('keyfile.json").text
    }
}
```

If you wanted to create a custom task, you probably have to create an actual instance of DockerRegistryCredentials to pass, like

```
task pushImageDev(type: DockerPushImage) {
    imageName "xxxxxx:5000/${project.name}-${appEnviroment}:${version}"

    registryCredentials(new DockerRegistryCredentials(...));
}
```

The reason is that `registryCredentials {...}` is an extension defined in [DockerExtension.groovy](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/DockerExtension.groovy), which does not work for custom tasks. It is not a setter for the field `registryCredentials` inside class `DockerPushImage`.

What also works is to nest a registry credentials call inside a `docker` call inside the custom task, though I am not sure why:

```
task pushImageDev(type: DockerPushImage) {
    appEnviroment = 'dev'
    imageName "xxxxxx/${project.name}-${appEnviroment}:${version}"

    docker {
        registryCredentials {
            username = "${nexusUsername}"
            password = "${nexusPassword}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok check the question. :)

Comment: Rollbacked as explained by https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18907462

Comment: I am the author, I want to include that alternative which works.